# Brownie downloads solc every time I run compile

Tags: visual-studio-code, solidity, brownie

I'm using Visual Studio Code and every time I run `brownie compile` I get this which takes a good while (and also I can't compile without internet connection):

[image]

I tried installing `solc` with pip but I don't know if it just doesn't work or what, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Has it completed downloading at least once?

Comment: @PatrickCollins It has, sometimes once it's completed the next time I run `brownie compile` it downloads it again, sometimes it doesn't. It's a pretty weird behavior but let's say it's just once per project which is still weird

Comment: Whats in your `~/.solcx` folder? That's where solidity versions are downloaded.

Comment: @PatrickCollins this is what's inside `~/.solcx` (using `ls -a`): `solc-v0.4.26, solc-v0.6.0, solc-v0.6.6, solc-v0.8.10, solc-v0.5.16, solc-v0.6.12, solc-v0.8.0`

Comment: Hmm... What version is it trying to install whenever it runs? What happens when it completes running? Could you copy paste the code output instead of the picture?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you change solidity versions you're essentially redownloading it again, you can't just downgrade or upgrade magically.